# halt in backgroundworker thread when using scintilla NET to not freeze the GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker, scintilla

The background worker halts when invoked to append text to a scintilla Controls, here is the partial code. After adding try catch logic, i still didn't get any exceptions!

```
 private delegate void DWrite(string text);
    private void Write(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            scintilla1.AppendText(text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

    }


    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        string x;
        while (true)
        {
            x = tcw.Read();
           // MessageBox.Show(x);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            try
            {
                scintilla1.Invoke(new DWrite(Write), x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        //    scintilla1.Update();
        }
```

I added this logic:

```
 static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        MessageBox.Show("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
    }

    public void doworkstuff()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                scintilla1.Invoke(new DWrite(Write), tcw.Read());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

The problem seems to be with the control it self, not allowing external threads to access to avoid deadlocks. is there a way that i can get the same functionality without having to use BGWorker?
the tcw.read() is a telnet client that streams input to the control, i want the streaming (i.e. tcw.read()) to continue until the users presses stop on the form!

Comment: Where is the code that starts the background worker?  Is it blocking the thread waiting for the background worker?

Comment: its is called on a button click method which writes the scintillaNET configuration file and then issues bw.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: There are no exceptions, the backgroundworker returns without adding the text and without reiterating on the while loop

Comment: Is the UI frozen, or is it remaining responsive?

Comment: Then what do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: it remains responsive but nothing happens,
if i remove the invoke line, i get the messageboxes correctly and i get the expected behavior. problem appears if i add the invoking line

Comment: Odds are an exception is being thrown and you're just not catching it.  Wrap the do work handler in a try/catch that logs the exception details somewhere.  Perhaps `scintilla1` is null, for example.

Comment: Add a try/catch in the `Invoke`, use `BeginInvoke`. `Invoke` without try/catch can cause your app to hang if the exception thrown  causes the process to halt or if it's ignored - nothing seems to happen. Another approach would be to add a listener to `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException`

Comment: i still dont get any exceptions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found a bug in ScintillaNET.

To handle interop between the managed Scintilla wrapper and the native Scintilla control, ScintillaNET overrides the WndProc method. In so doing, it appears the Windows Forms mechanism for marshaling calls back to the UI thread has been broken.

In the meantime, you can use the [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event which is there to do precisely the type of periodic UI update you are attempting.

After making sure you've set the BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress property to `true`, modify your code so that you use the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method in place of your Invoke method and handle the ProgressChanged event.

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    string x;
    while (true)
    {
        x = "Your telnet data";
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        worker.ReportProgress(-1, x);
    }
}

private void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.UserState as string;
    scintilla1.AppendText(text);
}
```

(full disclosure: I'm a ScintillaNET developer)

Answer (score 0):

You should put some breaking condition, your while loop is an infinite one!
If you use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke, the background worker wouldn't halt though!

```
scintilla1.BeginInvoke(new DWrite(Write), x);
```

Comment: NO, I tried to loop like this to see if this is whats causing the problem;
int = 0;
while(i<5)
{i++;//same code}.
same behaviour

Comment: Did you try simple invoking the method without the while loop?

Comment: No whiles, using BeginInvoke, same behaviour!

Comment: Few REFs
http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/workitem/33759
http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/discussions/221063

Comment: You can try doing the update of the UI in RunWorkerCompleted Event, which fires on the UI thread . However I am not sure that's what you need.